# Problema con RUTAS PROTEGIDAS VS RUTAS PUBLICAS en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

Estoy creando mi sistema de LOGIN y el problema que tengo es que mis rutas publicas solo se muestran cuando mi usuario no esta logeado. Si esta logeado no me deja llegar a ellas. Obviamente pasa lo mismo con las protegidas pero en ese caso esta bien.

Como podría lograr revertir el tema de las rutas publicas?
Las publicas se tienen que poder ver siempre.

App

```
return (
    <>
      <AuthContextProvider>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Navbar />
          <Routes>
            <Route element={<PublicRoute />}>
              <Route path="login" element={<LoginComp />} />
              <Route path="revisions" element={<Revisions />} />
              <Route path="*" element={<NotFoundComp />} />
            </Route>
            <Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
              <Route path="home" element={<Home />} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </AuthContextProvider>
      <Footer />
    </>
```

PrivateRoutes.js

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useAuthContext } from './authContext'

export default function PrivateRoute() {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuthContext()

  if (!isAuthenticated) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" />
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  )
}
```

publicroute.js

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useAuthContext } from './authContext'

export default function PublicRoute() {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuthContext()

  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return <Navigate to="home" />
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  )
}
```

authcontext

```
export const AuthContext = createContext()

export default function AuthContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(window.localStorage.getItem('login'))

  const login = useCallback(function () {
    window.localStorage.setItem('login', true)
    setIsAuthenticated(true)
  }, [])

  const logout = useCallback(function () {
    window.localStorage.removeItem('login', true)
    window.localStorage.removeItem('access', true)
    window.localStorage.removeItem('refresh', true)
    setIsAuthenticated(false)
  }, [])

  const value = useMemo(
    () => ({
      login,
      logout,
      isAuthenticated,
    }),
    [isAuthenticated, login, logout]
  )

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
}

AuthContextProvider.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.object,
}

export function useAuthContext() {
  return useContext(AuthContext)
}
```

Me obliga a escribir mas y ya no se que mas poner.
Creo que este es todo el codigo que se necesita.
Saludos y gracias !